# How do I explain the difference between fold and foldK?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In the context of a programmer newly learning functional programming and completing the online Scala Exercises for Cats [here](https://www.scala-exercises.org/cats/foldable), the following result seems puzzling:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

object Foo {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    println(Foldable[List].fold(List(None, Option("two"), Option("three"))))
    //Some("twothree")
    println(Foldable[List].foldK(List(None, Option("two"), Option("three"))))
    //Some("two")
}
```

I can follow the example for `fold` but not for `foldK`. The [documentation for foldK](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/b6903be83355da0a73bb35e70bb58a949d9c417a/core/src/main/scala/cats/Foldable.scala#L355) says:

> This method is identical to fold, except that we use the universal monoid (`MonoidK[G]`) to get a `Monoid[G[A]]` instance.

I don't understand how this difference would cause the behaviour seen above where somehow the third element in the list (`Option("three")`) is "ignored" for the `foldK`.

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fold` uses a Monoid[Option[A]] instance, and `cats/kernel/instances/option.scala` has following implementation for  `Monoid[Option[A]].combine` ,

```
def combine(x: Option[A], y: Option[A]): Option[A] =
    x match {
      case None => y
      case Some(a) =>
        y match {
          case None => x
          case Some(b) => Some(A.combine(a, b))
        }
    }
```

But `foldK` wants a `MoinoidK[Option]` instance and the answer for this difference is in implementation of `combineK` for `Option`,

If your look into `cats.instances.OptionInstances`, you will find following

```
  def combineK[A](x: Option[A], y: Option[A]): Option[A] = x orElse y
```

This should be explain things. I don't know if this is intended or just an overlooked deviation towards in-consistency in cats instances.

Comment: Thanks so much. The definition of `combineK` was the missing information